# Terraform: wait till the instance is "reachable"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible, terraform

I have some Terraform code with an `aws_instance` and a `null_resource`:

```
resource "aws_instance" "example" {
  ami           = data.aws_ami.server.id
  instance_type = "t2.medium"
  key_name      = aws_key_pair.deployer.key_name

  tags = {
    name = "example"
  }

  vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.main.id]
}

resource "null_resource" "example" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "ANSIBLE_HOST_KEY_CHECKING=False ansible-playbook -T 300 -i ${aws_instance.example.public_dns}, --user centos --private-key files/id_rsa playbook.yml"
  }
}
```

It kinda works, but sometimes there is a bug (probably when the instance in a pending state). When I rerun Terraform - it works as expected.

Question: How can I run local-exec only when the instance is running and accepting an SSH connection?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The `null_resource` is currently only going to wait until the `aws_instance` resource has completed which in turn only waits until the AWS API returns that it is in the `Running` state. There's a long gap from there to the instance starting the OS and then being able to accept SSH connections before your `local-exec` provisioner can connect.

One way to handle this is to use the `remote-exec` provisioner on the instance first as that has the ability to wait for the instance to be ready. Changing your existing code to handle this would look like this:

```
resource "aws_instance" "example" {
  ami           = data.aws_ami.server.id
  instance_type = "t2.medium"
  key_name      = aws_key_pair.deployer.key_name

  tags = {
    name = "example"
  }

  vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.main.id]


}

resource "null_resource" "example" {
  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    connection {
      host = aws_instance.example.public_dns
      user = "centos"
      private_key = file("files/id_rsa")
    }

    inline = ["echo 'connected!'"]
  }

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "ANSIBLE_HOST_KEY_CHECKING=False ansible-playbook -T 300 -i ${aws_instance.example.public_dns},  --user centos --private-key files/id_rsa playbook.yml"
  }
}
```

This will first attempt to connect to the instance's public DNS address as the `centos` user with the `files/id_rsa` private key. Once it is connected it will then run `echo 'connected!'` as a simple command before moving on to your existing `local-exec` provisioner that runs Ansible against the instance.

Note that just being able to connect over SSH may not actually be enough for you to then provision the instance. If your Ansible script tries to interact with your package manager then you may find that it is locked from the instance's user data script running. If this is the case you will need to remotely execute a script that waits for `cloud-init` to be complete first. An example script looks like this:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

while [ ! -f /var/lib/cloud/instance/boot-finished ]; do
  echo -e "\033[1;36mWaiting for cloud-init..."
  sleep 1
done
```

Comment: I feel like it a little bit "hacky" solution but it solves the problem. Thx

Answer (score 8):

Here is an Ansible-specific solution for this problem. Add this code to your playbook (there is also a pre_task clause if you use roles)

```
- name: will wait till reachable
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: no # important
  tasks:
    - name: Wait for system to become reachable
      wait_for_connection:

    - name: Gather facts for the first time
      setup:
```

Answer (score 4):

For cases where instances are not externally exposed (About 90% of the time in most of my projects), and SSM agent is installed on the target instance (newer AWS AMIs come [pre-loaded](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/sysman-install-ssm-agent.html) with it), you can leverage SSM to probe the instance. Here's some sample code:

```
instanceId=$1
echo "Waiting for instance to bootstrap ..."
tries=0
responseCode=1
while [[ $responseCode != 0 && $tries -le 10 ]]
do
  echo "Try # $tries"
  cmdId=$(aws ssm send-command --document-name AWS-RunShellScript --instance-ids $instanceId --parameters commands="cat /tmp/job-done.txt # or some other validation logic" --query Command.CommandId --output text)
  sleep 5
  responseCode=$(aws ssm get-command-invocation --command-id $cmdId --instance-id $instanceId --query ResponseCode --output text)
  echo "ResponseCode: $responseCode"
  if [ $responseCode != 0 ]; then
    echo "Sleeping ..."
    sleep 60
  fi
  (( tries++ ))
done
echo "Wait time over. ResponseCode: $responseCode"
```

Assuming you have AWS CLI installed locally, you can have this null_resource required before you act on the instance. In my case, I was building an AMI.

```
resource "null_resource" "wait_for_instance" {
  depends_on = [
    aws_instance.my_instance
  ]
  triggers = {
    always_run = "${timestamp()}"
  }
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "${path.module}/scripts/check-instance-state.sh ${aws_instance.my_instance.id}"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`provisioner "local-exec" { command = "aws ec2 wait instance-status-ok --instance-ids ${self.id}" }`

Answer (score 1):

In my case i was calling EC2 as a module to config multiple nodes, the best way that i found is to wait until the last node is reachable. Hope that this helps someone

```html
locals {
  anchor     = element(aws_instance.node[*].private_ip, 0)
  rest       = slice(aws_instance.node[*].private_ip, 1, var.count)
  rest_count = var.count - 1
}

resource "aws_instance" "node" {
  ami           = var.ami_id
  count         = var.count
  instance_type = var.type
[...]
  user_data = <<EOF
#!/bin/bash
[...]
EOF
}

resource "null_resource" "join_cluster" {
  count = local.rest_count

  # If an IP changes, these scripts will run again
  triggers = {
    nodes_ips = join(",", aws_instance.node.*.private_ip)
  }

  # Best way to wait until nodes are in "running" state to finish emqx cluster configuration
  # AWS profile is required
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "aws ec2 wait instance-status-ok --instance-ids ${aws_instance.node[local.rest_count].id}"
  }

  # Connection to the nodes. Security hardening doesn't allow executions from /tmp directory
  connection {
    type        = "ssh"
    host        = local.rest[count.index % local.rest_count]
    user        = "ubuntu"
    private_key = var.ssh_key
    agent       = false
    script_path = "/home/ubuntu/terraform_%RAND%.sh"
  }

  # Join the instances to the cluster
  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [
      "sudo emqx_ctl cluster join emqx@${local.anchor}"
    ]
  }

  depends_on = [aws_instance.node]
}
```